# Google sheets editor list for only full cells

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a program that will invite email addresses from a column of cells. However, I only want the cells that have content in them to be used in the program and the empty cells to be ignored. Since the cells are linked to a form, as soon as the program finds a single empty cell as it searches down the column, it should stop looking for more empty cells. This is what I have so far:

```
function addEditor() {
var sheet    = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('GuestList');
var Blank    = sheet.getRange('a51').getValue().isBlank;
for (var i = 2; Blank = true; i++){
  var Blank = sheet.getRange(2, 1, i, 1).isBlank;
    if (Blank === true){ break;
  }
 }
var Editors  = sheet.getRange(2, 1, i, 1);
  sheet.protect().addEditors([Editors]);
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are having with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function sendEmails() {
var glist=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('GuestList');
var gdata=glist.getDataRange().getValues();
for (var i=1;i<gdata.length;i++){
  if(gdata[i][0]){
    //sendEmail
  }else{
    break;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I used 'function emailCollabs() {
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('GuestList);
  var gdata=sheet.getRange('b216:b267').getValues();
for (var i=1;i<gdata.length;i++){
  if(gdata[i][0]){
    var Editors = sheet.getRange(2, 1, i, 216).getValues;
    sheet.protect().addEditors(Editors);
  }else{
    break;
  }
 }
}' and it says "cannot find method addEditors(function)"